# Why does my MacBook Pro (with Iris 5200) only output 1920x1200 via HDMI?

Tags: windows-8.1, resolution, hdmi, macbook-pro, external-display

I have a late-2013 15" retina MacBook Pro with an i7-4750HQ CPU and onboard Iris Pro 5200 graphics. And in case it makes any difference, I'm running Win8.1 on it.

When I connect this MBP to an external 2560 x 1440 monitor via HDMI, I'm puzzled to find that the displayed resolution on said external screen is only HD. (Actually, I think it was 1920 x 1200.)

Can anyone explain why the HDMI connection is not making use of the full capabilities of both the monitor and the Iris Pro graphics? Particularly when [Intel seem to state](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/quick-reference-guide-to-intel-processor-graphics/) that it should be capable of higher resolution.

Does it have anything to with the display running at 60Hz? (The above Intel link only offers a figure for HDMI running at 24Hz.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needs to be HDMI 1.4 to support 2k or 4k resolutions.

Based on my own experience & similar questions in this forum, use a Thunderbolt/mini-DisplayPort to DisplayPort or possibly DVI [I have had much better luck with DP]

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin, but if I use Thunderbolt then there's a problem with Bootcamp not picking up the device unless it's present at boot-up - nor can you sleep or hibernate a Thunderbolt-connected computer: http://www.macwindows.com/Thunderbolt-Limitations-of-Mac-running-Windows-and-getting-around-them.html  This means that it would be impractical to use Thunderbolt - and presumably DisplayPort as well.

Comment: I've only ever used it on a desktop that never sleeps, so I'm beyond my experience on the MBP, sorry - but it works booted into both Mavericks & Win 7 on Bootcamp; though it is always plugged in.

Comment: Late-2013 MBPs *do* have HDMI 1.4, right? Or is their implementation to support 4k via HDMI some proprietary solution?

Comment: yes, afaik it's full 1.4 spec - but does the cable & monitor also support it?

Comment: The monitor I was trying doesn't support HDMI 1.4. I was only asking so that I know one end of the cable would support it - no point getting a latest-spec monitor only to find that the MBP doesn't offer what I need. Thanks again, Tetsujin.

Comment: Welcome. Wish you luck.